# Rails HTML embedding not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4, each

so I'm trying to show some blog-type data on one of my pages. It works fine, but is posting the posts all at the end of the div as well.
Like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy3aw.png)

```html
<div class="style-2 mb-20 shadow bordered light-gray-bg news-margin col-md-5">
  <!-- page-title start -->
  <!-- ================ -->
  <h1 class="page-title">Latest News</h1>
  <div class="separator-2"></div>
  <!-- page-title end -->
  <p class="lead">The latest news will be posted here:</p>
  <div class="row grid-space-12">

    <%=@ news.each do |news| %>

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="image-box style-2 mb-20 shadow bordered text-center">
          <div class="overlay-container">
            <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-5x p-20"></i>
            <div class="overlay-to-top">
              <p class="small margin-clear"><em> <%= news.topic %> <br> <%= news.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d") %></em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="body">
            <h3><%= news.header %></h3>
            <div class="separator"></div>
            <p>
              <%=n ews.content %>
            </p>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-hvr hvr-shutter-out-horizontal margin-clear">Read More<i class="fa fa-arrow-right pl-10"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I had the = in with <%= news.each do |news| %>, which was printing that info out...